# Databinding MediaPlaybackItem to ListView Item in DataTemplate

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, binding, uwp

Hello i have the following listView :

```
<ListView x:Name="SongList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible" Height="615" Background="White"
          Opacity="0.5" SelectedValue="selectedFile"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MediaModels.MediaPlaybackItemsList  , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Margin="986,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294">
```

So in my itemSource i bind a list of MediaPlaybackItem .Thats fine everything works good except i dont know how to bind the artist and title for each mediaplayback item to the dataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#404040" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="282" Height="80">
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GetDisplayProperties().MusicProperties.Artist}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                           Margin="82,10,10,0" />
                                <Grid Margin="0,0,-140,0">
                                    <Image Source="Images/Album.png" Width="70" Height="70" Margin="0,0,350,0" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

THe `MediaPlaybacKItem` class has method `GetDisplayProperties().MusicProperties.Artist/Title/`etc. which returns `string`. I can access these `properties` only through this `GetDisplayProperties` method , so how can i bind the result of it  in data Template ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a method to a property like that. Instead, expose a property in your `MediaPlaybackItem` that returns the `MusicProperties` object.

MediaPlaybackItem class

```
public MusicPropertiesType MusicProperties
{
  get 
  {
    return this.GetDisplayProperties().MusicProperties;
  }
}
```

Now you can bind that to your `ItemTemplate`.

XAML

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderBrush="#404040" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Width="282" Height="80">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MusicProperties.Artist}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                           Margin="82,10,10,0" />
                <Grid Margin="0,0,-140,0">
                    <Image Source="Images/Album.png" Width="70" Height="70" Margin="0,0,350,0" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: MediaPlaybackItem is UWP library(not my own class) and c# doesnt support properties extension , so i cannot use your solution

Comment: You might want to add a `ViewModel` layer in your application. And that's where you should bind your `View`.